# Inserting a term into a custom taxonomy

Tags: custom-taxonomy

Made this custom taxonomy that'll control layout on single posts, basically I want to add two options, Layout 1 and Layout 2.

```
// Register Custom Taxonomy
function custom_taxonomy() {

    $labels = array(
        'name'                       => _x( 'Layout', 'Taxonomy General Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'singular_name'              => _x( 'Layout', 'Taxonomy Singular Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'menu_name'                  => __( 'Taxonomy', 'text_domain' ),
        'all_items'                  => __( 'All Items', 'text_domain' ),
        'parent_item'                => __( 'Parent Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'parent_item_colon'          => __( 'Parent Item:', 'text_domain' ),
        'new_item_name'              => __( 'New Item Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'add_new_item'               => __( 'Add New Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'edit_item'                  => __( 'Edit Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'update_item'                => __( 'Update Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'separate_items_with_commas' => __( 'Separate items with commas', 'text_domain' ),
        'search_items'               => __( 'Search Items', 'text_domain' ),
        'add_or_remove_items'        => __( 'Add or remove items', 'text_domain' ),
        'choose_from_most_used'      => __( 'Choose from the most used items', 'text_domain' ),
        'not_found'                  => __( 'Not Found', 'text_domain' ),
    );
    $capabilities = array(
        'manage_terms' => 'foobar',
        'edit_terms'   => 'foobar',
        'delete_terms' => 'foobar',
        'assign_terms' => 'foobar' 
    );
    $args = array(
        'labels'                     => $labels,
        'hierarchical'               => true,
        'public'                     => true,
        'show_ui'                    => true,
        'show_admin_column'          => false,
        'show_in_nav_menus'          => false,
        'show_tagcloud'              => false,
        'capabilities'               => $capabilities,
    );
    register_taxonomy( 'Layout', array( 'post' ), $args );

}

// Hook into the 'init' action
add_action( 'init', 'custom_taxonomy', 0 );
```

Capabilities are set to invalid values to stop terms from being edited, but I can't get wp_insert_term working.

Adding two terms to my custom taxonomy can't be so hard, right?

Using this to insert a term doesn't work, although if I changed my custom taxonomy name to 'category', ie WP default it works just fine. What gives?

```
function example_insert_category() {
    $parent_term = term_exists( 'layout' ); // array is returned if taxonomy is given
$parent_term_id = $parent_term['term_id']; // get numeric term id
    wp_insert_term(
        'Example Category',
        'layout',
        array(
          'description' => 'This is an example category created with wp_insert_term.',
          'slug'        => 'example-category'
        )
    );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'example_insert_category' );
```

Comment: As promised, I posted the code to the plugin. Hope this helps :-)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**EDIT 2**

As promised, here is the code to the plugin.

It is a known fact that custom taxonomies and custom post types should go into a plugin, and **not** in your theme. I have stripped parts from my plugin.

**HOW IT WORKS**

The taxonomy is registered as normal through the plugin. For any info regarding this, you can go and check out `register_taxonomy`. The part that I needed to highlight and what is relevant to this question, is how to insert new terms.

To insert terms through `wp_insert_terms` are quick and easy, but this code can also hurt loading time if not used correctly. The idea is to run that function once, and then never again, almost like removing it after the first run.

To accomplish this, you are going to hook your function to `register_activation_hook`. This hook runs once, that is when the plugin is activated, it will not rerun on page refresh. The only time it will fire again is when the plugin is deactivated and activated again

So you first need to register your taxonomy as you can't assign terms to a taxonomy that does not exists. Once your taxonomy is registered, you can insert your terms. Remember, this action will only take place once, and that is when the plugin is activated. If you need to add terms, you need to deactivate the plugin and activate it again

You want to also first check if a term exists before trying to create and insert it.

Here is the plugin code

```
<?php
/**
Plugin Name: Create terms
Plugin URI: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/163541/31545
Description: Create terms
Version: 1.0
Author: Pieter Goosen
License: GPLv2 or later
*/
class Test_Terms {

    function __construct() {
        register_activation_hook( __FILE__,array( $this,'activate' ) );
        add_action( 'init', array( $this, 'create_cpts_and_taxonomies' ) );
    } 

    function activate() {
        $this->create_cpts_and_taxonomies();
        $this->register_new_terms();
    }

    function create_cpts_and_taxonomies() {

        $args = array( 
            'hierarchical'                      => true,  
            'labels' => array(
                'name'                          => _x('Test Tax', 'taxonomy general name' ),
                'singular_name'                 => _x('Test Tax', 'taxonomy singular name'),
                'search_items'                  => __('Search Test Tax'),
                'popular_items'                 => __('Popular Test Tax'),
                'all_items'                     => __('All Test Tax'),
                'edit_item'                     => __('Edit Test Tax'),
                'edit_item'                     => __('Edit Test Tax'),
                'update_item'                   => __('Update Test Tax'),
                'add_new_item'                  => __('Add New Test Tax'),
                'new_item_name'                 => __('New Test Tax Name'),
                'separate_items_with_commas'    => __('Seperate Test Tax with Commas'),
                'add_or_remove_items'           => __('Add or Remove Test Tax'),
                'choose_from_most_used'         => __('Choose from Most Used Test Tax')
            ),  
            'query_var'                         => true,  
            'rewrite'                           => array('slug' =>'test-tax')        
        );
        register_taxonomy( 'test_tax', array( 'post' ), $args );
    }

    function register_new_terms() {
        $this->taxonomy = 'test_tax';
        $this->terms = array (
            '0' => array (
                'name'          => 'Tester 1',
                'slug'          => 'tester-1',
                'description'   => 'This is a test term one',
            ),
            '1' => array (
                'name'          => 'Tester 2',
                'slug'          => 'tester-2',
                'description'   => 'This is a test term two',
            ),
        );  

        foreach ( $this->terms as $term_key=>$term) {
                wp_insert_term(
                    $term['name'],
                    $this->taxonomy, 
                    array(
                        'description'   => $term['description'],
                        'slug'          => $term['slug'],
                    )
                );
            unset( $term ); 
        }

    }
}
$Test_Terms = new Test_Terms();
```

**EDIT 1**

Your problem with inserting terms is your hook. [`after_setup_theme`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/after_setup_theme) runs before [`init`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/init), meaning that you are trying to insert a term to a taxonomy that is not registered yet.

I would suggest that you move your [`wp_insert_term`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_term) function to inside your init function, just below `register_taxonomy`

It is also advisable to first check if a term exists ([`term_exists`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/term_exists)) before inserting it

Example:

```
// Register Custom Taxonomy
function custom_taxonomy() {

   //CODE TO REGISTER TAXONOMY

   if( !term_exists( 'Example Category', 'layout' ) ) {
       wp_insert_term(
           'Example Category',
           'layout',
           array(
             'description' => 'This is an example category created with wp_insert_term.',
             'slug'        => 'example-category'
           )
       );
   }
}

// Hook into the 'init' action
add_action( 'init', 'custom_taxonomy', 0 );
```

*Please note, this is untested*

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

Custom taxonomy names (and custom post type names) need to comply to a very specific set of rules, otherwise you will encounter pitfalls that there are no work around for.

Here is a guide line when choosing names for custom taxonomies (and custom post types)

1. The following are **not** allowed in custom taxonomy names and custom post type names

   - Capital letters or camelcase
   - Any type of special character, except underscores (`_`)
   - Spaces
   - More than 32 characters for taxonomies and 20 for post types
   - Any [reserved names](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy#Reserved_Terms), and please note, this goes for **any** custom naming convention, not just taxonomy names.
2. If there are more than one word in a taxonomy name, they **have to** be separated by underscores, not hyphens (`-`). I have been challenged that hyphens are the way to go for SEO in URL's for taxonomy names. It is true, that is why there are rewrite rules to adjust your URL accordingly. Never change taxonomy names or post type names for URL SEO purposes

Also, you should remove that weird capabilities. It might also create a problem

If this does not solve your issue, please add the code that you use with `wp_insert_term`

Reference:

- [`register_taxonomy`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy)
- [`register_post_type`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type)

Comment: After looking into the [source](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.0/src/wp-includes/taxonomy.php#L324) I'm a bit stumped, because the `$taxonomy` parameter does not get sanitized at all, if the `query_var` argument gets set to `true`. Thats quite unbelievable actually. And otherwise it gets sanitized via [`sanitize_title_with_dashes()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/sanitize_title_with_dashes), which will, nomen es omen, replace stuff with dashes all over the place. Which is unbelievable too, as they shouldn't be used.

Comment: Aside from the fact, you can use numbers as you like, anywhere, so in the beginning too, although you can  read everywhere that this shouldn't be done. Couldn't find a definite reason against numbers though. Unlike for dashes, were at least there is a statement »Also, if the post type contains dashes you will not be able to add columns to the custom post type's admin page (using the 'manage_<Custom Post Type Name>_posts_columns' action).« on the codex page of [`register_post_type()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#Reserved_Post_Types).

Comment: Although it is somewhat hidden in the »Reserved Post Types« section. I don't know such - potentially or definitely problematic - things should be enforced. Otherwise it is just asking for trouble without a good reason.

Comment: Wordpress does have its flaws, must agree. Some are actual crimes :-). I think dashes is one of the most talked subject and also most used in names. Its failure is quite evident when you start looking at the template hierarchy. Create a taxonomy with two words like my-taxonomy separated by a dash, and create a taxonomy template taxonomy-my-taxonomy.php and you'll see failure. I have read the number thing somewhere, need to recheck that again though. This is a stay safe list that I always use to stay safe, and it has worked perfectly. Thanks for all your info, appreciated

Comment: As do I, but just because I learned it from the beginning the right way. As I learned the most I know from [wordpress.se] and the smart and experienced people on here. So there are a lot of mistakes I never actually made myself.

Comment: It is my pleasure. Enjoy :-)

Comment: Imho should this answer be protected. Details in this answer/example are very important and it is not often enough pointed at in the Codex.

Comment: I believe the check if the term exists aren't necessary as the wp_insert_term function contains a check right at the start.