# Set object terms not working on plugin activation

Tags: custom-post-types, plugins, plugin-development, custom-taxonomy

I am trying to create a couple of custom posts and set a custom taxonomy term to it on plugin activation. I am using the register plugin activation hook to do it. The posts are created properly, but I the post term is not being set. I am using `wp_set_object_terms` to do it. What could be the possible cause?

My code resembles this:

```
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'insert_latest_books' );

public function insert_latest_books() {
    //Get the latest books
    $data = new Data_Fetcher();
    $latest_books = $data->get_latest_books();

    foreach($latest_books as $latest_book) {
        //Create a book post for each latest book
        $book = [
            'post_type' => 'book',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'post_title' => $latest_book->name,
            'post_content' => $latest_book->description
        ];

        $book_id = wp_insert_post($book);

        //TODO: Not working on plugin activation
        wp_set_object_terms($book_id, array('latest'), 'label');
        set_book_thumbnail($book_id, $latest_book->name, $latest_book->preview_image_url);
        update_post_meta($book_id, 'book_code', $latest_book->embed_code);
        update_post_meta($book_id, 'book_pages', $latest_book->length);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your issue is that you are trying to insert terms before your taxonomy is registered. Have a look at my answer to something similar [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/163543/31545)

Comment: Thank you! Why doesn't it work just like `register_post_type` works on the `init` action hook?

Comment: It still works the same, but the issue here is that by the time `init` fires, your plugin has already registered and done what you asked it to do. What I have done in my code is to only insert the terms ones the `init` hook has fired to register the taxonomy, the taxonomy still gets registered on the `init` hook

Comment: @PieterGoosen Great! I read your answer thoroughly and realized you're registering the taxonomy on plugin activation and hooking it to the `init` action as suggested in the codex. Did the same and it worked. Please add an answer so that I can accept it!

Comment: Just upvote my answer in the link and post whatevert you have as an answer. Unfortunately I don't have the time to post a complete answer ;-)

Comment: Sounds good! I already upvoted that answer! But will post mine here and accept that. Thank you very much. You made me understand a fundamental issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I learned from the comments by @Pieter Goosen and @Ignat.B, and @Pieter Goosen's answer [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/163543/31545), that I need to register the taxonomy on plugin activation, and insert the term. Then I need to hook the taxonomy registration code to the `init` action hook as suggested by the codex. This will ensure that when I insert the term on plugin activation, I have the taxonomy already registered and with `init` I follow WordPress's instruction to use init for that purpose.

The pseudo code:

```
function register_tax() {
    //Register the taxonomy
}


function activate() {
    register_tax();
    wp_insert_term(...);
}

register_activation_hook('...', 'activate');
add_action('init', 'register_tax');
```

Hope this helps someone stuck in a similar situation. Pieter's answer is really helpful if you need explanation.

Answer (score 2):

`register_activation_hook` is one-time only activation hook. It can be used for database structure creation, as example, that needs to fire only on plugin activation trigger.

In order to set a custom taxonomy you need a hook that will fire not just once, but per every WordPress load. Such as `init`.

Use `add_action( 'init', 'YOUR_CALLBACK' );` to achieve that

Comment: If you read my question description, I am using the `init` hook to create the taxonomy. I am implementing the solution by @Pieter Goosen.

Comment: You mean in the comments? Confirmed. the Pieter answer is more descriptive + shows how to register taxonomy on both init and withing registration.

Comment: Yes @Ignat.B! I should have read your comment earlier, it would have saved me some time in understanding the code. Thanks! Voted up.