# Why is this custom taxonomy showing in the database?

Tags: plugins, custom-taxonomy, customization

I have created a plugin that [add geographic data to Wordpress](https://he.wordpress.org/plugins/geoareas/). According to [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/213429/34330) the taxonomy data should not be stored in the database, however it seems to be stored:

```
mysql> select * from wp_term_taxonomy where taxonomy='geoareas' limit 10;
+------------------+---------+----------+-------------+--------+-------+
| term_taxonomy_id | term_id | taxonomy | description | parent | count |
+------------------+---------+----------+-------------+--------+-------+
|              953 |     699 | geoareas |             |      0 |     2 |
|              954 |     700 | geoareas |             |    699 |     0 |
|              955 |     701 | geoareas |             |    700 |     0 |
|              956 |     702 | geoareas |             |    700 |     0 |
|              957 |     703 | geoareas |             |    700 |     0 |
|              958 |     704 | geoareas |             |    700 |     0 |
|              959 |     705 | geoareas |             |    700 |     0 |
|              960 |     706 | geoareas |             |    700 |     0 |
|              961 |     707 | geoareas |             |    700 |     0 |
|              962 |     708 | geoareas |             |    700 |     0 |
+------------------+---------+----------+-------------+--------+-------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**Why is that data stored in the database**? And what would be the proper way to remove the data on `register_deactivation_hook` since `wp_delete_term()` seems to only remove the terms and not the entire taxonomy from the database. Do I manually need to remove all Term-Post and Term-CustomPostType associations in the database, and then all references to the taxonomy itself? Or is there an internal WP function that I should be using? The obvious `wp_delete_taxonomy()` does not exist!

**EDIT:** It seems to me that all the **taxonomy data** storded in the database is stored in the `wp_term_taxonomy`, `wp_terms`, and `wp_term_relationships` tables. Would these three queries be sufficient to purge the **taxonomy data** from the database on `register_deactivation_hook()`?

```
DELETE tr FROM wp_term_taxonomy tt INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships tr ON tt.term_taxonomy_id=tr.term_taxonomy_id WHERE taxonomy='geoareas';

DELETE tt FROM wp_term_taxonomy tt INNER JOIN wp_terms t ON tt.term_id=t.term_id WHERE taxonomy='geoareas';

DELETE FROM wp_term_taxonomy WHERE taxonomy='geoareas';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taxonomy "data" is indeed stored in the database. Taxonomy "definitions" are not.

The stuff you put into a call to `register_taxonomy` is not the data, it's the definition of that data. Stuff you add, like categories or tags, is the data, and yes, it goes in the taxonomy tables like any other taxonomy data.

You need to call `register_taxonomy` every time so that WordPress knows the taxonomy exists and how to deal with it. The data from the taxonomy comes from the database. Your definition of the taxonomy comes from the code.

Additional:

The question of how you should delete data entered by the user actually is more complex than just the technical means. All the means you mention work, but the real question is whether or not you *should* delete that data. Maybe the user put a lot of hard work into defining those geoareas themselves. If they remove and reinstall your plugin and the data is now just vanished forever, then that's kind of a terrible thing.

Also, you absolutely should not remove such data on `register_deactivation_hook`, because people can deactivative and reactivate a plugin easily. If you were going to remove data, it would be on an uninstall.php file in the plugin (which, unsurprisingly, only runs on an actual uninstall of the plugin, and not mere deactivation). A better approach might simply be to provide the user with a "wipe all the data" button instead. Put control of their data into their own hands.

If the data in question is unchanging and created automatically somehow, then regenerating it after a fresh install might make sense, but that's pretty rarely the case for taxonomies. Might want to reconsider your overall strategy instead.

Comment: Thank you, the distinction makes sense. When removing a plugin that defines a custom taxonomy, then how should the taxonomy's terms be removed? If I call wp_delete_term() on each term is that sufficient? Might I just run "DELETE FROM wp_term_taxonomy WHERE taxonomy='geoareas'" and be done with it quicker?

Comment: I have updated the question with three database queries which it seems to me would remove the data. Would you mind taking a look at the `EDIT` portion at the bottom of the OP to see if that makes sense? Thank you very much for lending your expertise.

Comment: Added more to my answer about deleting data.

Comment: Thank you Otto, I completely agree with your assessment about when to remove the data. I'll see if I can pop up a dialogue to give them an option to remove all associations on uninstall, or if I'll have to resort to a "wipe" button. Your expertise is invaluable and your willingness to share it is very, very much appreciated.