# Insert terms for custom taxonomy on plugin activation, or each page load (init hook)

Tags: plugin-development, custom-taxonomy, activation, terms, register-taxonomy

Consider a plugin which adds a custom Taxonomy and then fills the taxonomy with a large term hierarchy (tens of hierarchical terms, may become hundreds in specific installations). I understand that `register_taxonomy()` does not store data in the database, therefore [it must be used via the `init` hook](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/213428/use-register-taxonomy-in-register-activation-hook) so that the taxonomy is registered on each page load. However, `wp_insert_term()` [does store data in the database](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/215465/why-is-this-custom-taxonomy-showing-in-the-database).

With that in mind, would it be preferable to run `wp_insert_term()` from `register_activation_hook()` after ensuring that `register_taxonomy()` has run? And then run only `register_taxonomy()` on the 'init' hook for each page load?

For reference, my specific use case is the [GeoAreas](https://wordpress.org/plugins/geoareas/) WP plugin, which currently has about fifty terms. I am develping the next version of the plugin which will support more diverse geographical areas and should support a few hundreds of terms for large geographical areas such as Europe or the US.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

50 is relatively not much, and you should create them on the plugin activation hook.

For more then 100 (just pulled the number out of my ass ;) do your own testing on some slow shared hosting) I would create a settings page and initialize the DB from there. The reason is that users do not expect plugin activation to take long and might think that something is wrong, but there is no way to have a kind of "this might take a minute" message at activation time.

Whatever you are deciding to do, don't do it on the `init` hook as it is used by front end, do it only on hooks that are related to admin.

Comment: The terms are used in `wp_dropdown_categories()` for HTML select lists, so it needs to be available before any HTML is sent out. Therefore I propose to only invoke `register_taxonomy()` in the 'init' hook, and insert the terms only once: on install or from the initialize page that you suggest.

Comment: @dotancohen, you should never write to the DB when serving front end.

Comment: I'm sorry, I wasn't clear. I would invoke `wp_insert_term()` (which writes to the DB) only from within `register_activation_hook()`, but invoke `register_taxonomy()` (which does not write to the DB) on the 'init' hook. Thank you for clarifying that this is the proper method.